# asp.net C# get final page source of a webpage

Tags: c#, webclient

I'm trying to get the FINAL source of a webpage. I am using webclient openRead method, but this method is only returning the initial page source. After the source downloads, there is a javascript that runs and collect the data that I need in a different format and my method will be looking for something that got completely changed. 
What I am talking about is exactly like the difference between:

1. right-click on a webpage -> select view source
2. access the developer tools

Look at this site to know what I am talking about: http://www.augsburg.edu/history/fac_listing.html and watch how any of the email is displayed using each option. I think what happening is that the first will show you the initial load of the page. The second will show you the final page html. The webclient only lets me do option #1.

here is the code that will only return option #1. Oh I need to do this from a console application. Thank you!

```
private static string GetReader(string site)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    try
    {
        data = client.OpenRead(site);
        reader = new StreamReader(data);
    }
    catch
    {
        return "";
    }
    return reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: user1019042 : I am also having same problem can you please let me known did you get any solution for this requirement you have posted. i am using HttpWebrequest and HttpResponse for the same.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13666087/getting-page-source-of-web-pages-which-fire-ajax-request-to-server-after-first-l

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution to my problem. 
I ended up using Selenium-WebDriver PageSource property. It worked beautifully!

Learn about Selenium and Webdriver. It is an easy thing to learn. It helps for testing and on this!